# How to bring back constraints deleted by mistake on Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I accidentally clicked on Clear Constraints while working on an Xcode project. Command + Z doesn't seem to bring the constraints back, is there something I could do to recover the constraints in the view?

Comment: In the absence of source control management, I don't think so, but I wager the "add missing constraints" feature will probably get you pretty close, inferring what constraints should be added on the basis of where the frames currently are. It won't be perfect, but it's going to be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using SCM the only option I can think of would be to close Xcode without saving and hope that they are preserved with the last save state.